# Is possible send pdf file to remote printers with same ip-address?

Tags: c#, sockets, pdf, printing

I have use Socket to send pdf file to remote printer
and here is my code

```
class Program
{

    public static void SendPdfToPrint(string ipAddress)
    {

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
        clientSocket.SendTimeout = 600000;

        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);

        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(
                               Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())), "Printer.pdf"));

            clientSocket.Send(fileBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Send Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); 
        }


        clientSocket.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendPdfToPrint("my IP address");
    }
}
```

This code is successfully send pdf file and print it out in my local printer, but my remote printer get socket exception with this:

> system.net.sockets.socketexception an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

And my remote printers have same Ip-address.
I just can't figure out what wrong with this exception?
Or maybe is my remote printer setting is wrong?
and Is possible send pdf file to different printer with same ip-address?

Comment: so to have the sane IP its on a different network  - how are you connecting to that

Comment: Same IP but different name,so it not possible?

Comment: i didnt say that - the problem is normally if you link even via vpn often the remote end would complain cos your network matched theirs and refuse.  if you do it over the internet NAT is usualy involved so you dont connect to the same IP you connect to a translated address for the internet so even if you have the same IP the router is working it out.  FYI you and i could have the same ip right now, but the internet sees me as my router/translated IP and yours as yours.. and those wont be the same.. so. How do you connect to the network that has a device with the same IP a yours.. its important

Comment: Or maybe I should not use socket instead of smtp?

Comment: I think you need to stop on this question and start a new one with proper details.  What has smtp got to do with it